# Cannot run Starling helloworld when using source code in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I have recently installed FlashDevelop 4.4.3 and Starling 1.3.0.

I followed the [getting started tutorial](http://gamua.com/starling/first-steps/) of Starling.

I can run the tutorial when I put `starling.swc` into `lib` directory and after making "Add to Library".

But if I remove starling.swc from lib directory and instead copy source codes (`com` and `starling` directories inside `starling\src`) of starling framework into my project folder then I get the following error:

```
C:\projects\ch01_01\src\starling\display\BlendMode.as(42): col: 32 Error: Access of undefined property Context3DBlendFactor
```

The same error occurs also when I set the classpath to `<starling-installation>\starling\src`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy anything. Just use the folder with your starling source.
Your classpath should always point to *src* directory. It won't work if you point to *starling* directory.
[image]

Comment: Please, share your project via dropbox or something, let me take a look)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely target wrong flash player version.
 set it to 11.5 or something higher.